# In javafx, first default button does not work even after removing second default button

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

It would be great if some one could help me with the issue described here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087722

I know it is a bug, but I would be thankful if someone can provide any workaround for the same.

Comment: the bug report seems to have a work-around (at least a description of such) - so what exactly is the problem? What did you try?

Comment: actually, it might not even be a bug: to me it sounds more like a missing feature - fx simply doesn't enforce nor has any support for having a _single_ button with defaultButtonProperty true. It's left to application code to guarantee/update/restore the default property as needed (you don't want to have more than one button looking like the default anyway)